# Hiding image after clicking it on dropbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to hide the image after it is clicked for the dropbox in my navigation bar. How can I hide it after it is clicked?
Here is my script:

```js
<script>
var menuList = document.getElementById("menuList");

menuList.style.maxHeight = "0px";

function togglemenu() {
    if (menuList.style.maxHeight == "0px") {
        menuList.style.maxHeight = "130px";
    } else {
        menuList.style.maxHeight = "0px";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: it would be useful to have some html to get an idea of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the height, change the visibility of the object by using `menuList.style.display`.

`if(menuList.style.maxHeight == "0px")` >> `if (menuList.style.display === "none")`
`menuList.style.maxHeight = "130px";` >> `menuList.style.display = "none";`
`menuList.style.maxHeight = "0px";` >> `menuList.style.display = "block";` (or `menuList.style.display = "";`)

Take a look at [w3schools 'js toggle hide show'](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp)

Comment: that depends if you want it to be animatable or not.

Comment: id="menu-button" is the ID for my image button. I forgot to include it.

Comment: I need the image button to be invisible onclick. So if I click the image, the dropbox will go down and the image will be gone

Answer (score 0):

When handling this kind of behaviour I would recomend using classes.

so for example.

```js
const menuList = document.getElementById('menuList');

const button = document.getElementById('menu-button');

const openClass = 'menu-list--open';

function toggle() {
  if (menuList.classList.contains(openClass)) {
    button.style.display = "inline-block"; 
    menuList.classList.remove(openClass)
  }
  else {
    button.style.display = "none"; 
    menuList.classList.add(openClass)
  }
}

button.addEventListener('click', ()=> toggle())
menuList.addEventListener('click', ()=> toggle())
```

```css
.menu-list {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out max-height;
  background-color: red;
  height: 130px;
}

.menu-list--open {
 max-height: 130px;
}

#menu-button {
position:absolute;
top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="menu-button">click me</button>
<div id="menuList" class="menu-list">

<div/>
```

that should ensure that your button with id menu-button is hidden while your menu is open